# RemoteApp error Remote Desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer because there is a time or date difference

Tags: remote-desktop, remoteapp, rdweb

I'm getting error 'Remote Desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer because there is a time or date difference between your computer and the remote computer.' when i'm accessing a publish RemoteApp application. This was happening to a few Windows 7 clients machine. We have more than 100 users and only like less than 10 users getting this issue. Below troubleshooting already tried but does not work.

1. Change the CMOS battery of client machine
2. Date and Time are the same with the server
3. Tried using IP address but the same error
4. Can ping using the server DNS name and FQDN. Server DNS name was manually added on the client HOST file
5. Can RDP to the server using mstsc/RDC
6. If using RDWEB 'Connect to Remote PC', can connect if using IP address but the same error if using DNS name.
7. NSLookup resolved properly if using ip address but not with DNS name.
8. Other client machine can still access the Remoteapp even if the NSLookup for DNS name is not resolvable.

I'm thinking it is a DNS issues but most users can access it. Hope you can provide next step how to fixed this.

Thanks in advance.

Server: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: What kind of RDS setup do you have - is it a single server, or a farm? Have you checked through the RemoteApp settings? Is it possible the server has one DNS name which you added to the hosts file, so you can connect to the server using `mstsc`, but the RemoteApp settings are referencing another name that some clients cannot resolve?

Comment: AD is built on DNS, never forget that. Thus why the resolve does not work? A side note, please check the timezone, as the server will not like that if same hour, but in another timezone

Comment: timezone is the same.

Comment: remote server is located in datacenter and has its own DNS and configured in a domain. Users are located in different site with it's own DNS server and not part of the domain, WORKGROUP only. On the client machine i added the FQDN/DNS name in the host.

Comment: It happens on singe (test) and multiple server(production) farm.